# What is the probability X1-X2 is zero for terms real i.i.d random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

The case when X (i.e., equiv. to the X1, X2) is finite discrete is clear (it's the sum of squares of the point masses?), but what about in general?  Is it a function of the probabilities of the discontinuities of X or X1-X2? (Per the i.i.d. condition, X1-X2 has mean zero and variance 2Var(X).)

Comment: "Per the i.i.d. condition, X-X has mean zero and variance 2Var(X)." Are you claiming that $X$ and $X$ (or possibly $X$ and $-X$ are _independent_ random variables? (_independent_ is what that first "i" in "i.i.d'" stands for). Loosely speaking, $X$ and $Y$ are independent if knowing the value of one of them does not tell you anything (that you did not already know) about the value of the other. So how can $X$ be independent of $X$? or of $-X$?

Comment: My notation needs correction.  Re-write it as X1-X2 with X1, X2 i.i.d., not "X-X".

Answer (score 0):

$X$ cannot be independent from itself. Also,  $E(X-X)=Var(X-X)=0$. The equality you stated only works of $Var(X)=0$.

Comment: Yes. See revised wording.